# Programmatically convert 2D image to 3D renderable using android sceneform

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform

All the tutorials and blogs out there show how to build Renderable:

```
ModelRenderable.builder()
               .setSource(this, <Path of 3D model>)
               .build()
               .thenAccept(renderable -> myRedenderable = renderable)
```

using the sceneform plugin in android studio. But I would like to build a 3D Renderable on the fly from a 2D .png image or something uploaded by the user. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Use ViewRendarable to place a 2d View

```
// Build a renderable from a 2D View.
    CompletableFuture<ViewRenderable> solarControlsStage =
        ViewRenderable.builder().setView(this, R.layout.file_name).build();
```

To find more detail about placing 2D View Look at [google Ar solar system sample](https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/tree/master/samples/solarsystem)

Comment: @MathanN, I think this would convert 2D image that is packaged in my app. But my question is how would I let my user upload a .png or .jpg image and then convert the image into renderable? I hope I am clear.

Comment: You should add uploaded image into layout using ImageView then render the layout.